# How do I display first image when preloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'd be grateful for somebody to review the javascript (jQuery) code on a site I'm developing http://staging.intatec.co.uk/.

I'm doing a slideshow effect on the first page (using the [CrossSlide plugin](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/)) and will have a significant number of large images to run through. What I'd like to do is:

1) Display a loading graphic whilst the first image loads;

2) Once it has loaded, display the first image whilst loading the remaining images.

I think I'm kind of there but sometimes it works/sometimes it doesn't/sometimes it glitches. The code I have is below:

```
$('.hero-image').hide();
  $(function() {
    var firstImage = $('.hero-image:first-child')
    $(firstImage).load(function() {
      var images = $('.hero-image')
      var crossSlideArray = new Array
      var direction = "up"
      images.each(function() {
        crossSlideArray.push({ src:$(this).attr('src'),dir:direction,href:"http://www.intatec.co.uk/product_groups/" + $(this).attr('alt'),alt:$(this).attr('alt').capitalize()})
        direction = (direction == "up") ? "down" : "up"
      })

      $('#hero-holder').removeClass("loading").delay(200).after("<div id='caption'></div>");

      $('#hero-holder').crossSlide({
        speed: 40,
        fade: 1.5
      }, crossSlideArray, function(idx,img,idxOut,imgOut) {

      $('#caption').html("<h3>" + img.alt + "</h3>").animate({opacity: 0.8});
    });
  })
})
```

Thanks

Robin

Comment: Can you describe what happens right now? I get a progress bar at first, but it disappears before the images start scrolling.

Comment: Can you post some of the specific code about this issue? I don't know where your code is that would handle this.

Comment: finally a good site to explore... scripts! ;)

Comment: Hi Jan, the images aren't bad, are they? ;-) At the moment, I'm fairly sure it's loading all the images before the progress bar disappears. I'm hopefully looking for a smooth fade from the progress bar to the first image once the first image has loaded.

Comment: This page loads the first image and displays before showing the slideshow images. It uses cycle-lite, but I think the concept is the same as far as that goes. [MAC Slideshow](http://www.maineaccessibility.com/products.asp?article=3060)